# How to completely update the whole UI entirely in React

Tags: reactjs, routes

This is code in App.js . The other two elements just return statements in  tags`

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import CreateAccPage from './pages/CreateAccPage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <button><Link to="CreateAccount">Create Account</Link></button>
            <button><Link to="LoginPage">Login</Link></button>
          </div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="CreateAccount" element={<CreateAccPage/>}/>
            <Route path="LoginPage" element={<LoginPage/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

`
I am trying to switch between pages, successfully done it using route. The issue is, when the new component is loaded, the buttons still remains on the screen. its like everything in the first componet is a navigation bar. How can i change the whole UI to an entirely new component

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: i have updated the question @WiktorZychla

Comment: So what you want to do with these briefings buttons? Hide them when Login Page is

Comment: Yeah, I want it to be a completely new page. for example how an application would switch from the login page and now you have a dashboard @WiktorZychla

Comment: First, delete the div from your router. Then, create a new component and put the div into the new component. Then, use the new component in the `CreateAccount` page but **not** in `LoginPage`.

Comment: thank you @WiktorZychla